# Solution of outer product matrix ODE yields the solution of the original matrix ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE for matrix function $X(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$, such that the outer product $P(t) = X(t)X(t)^\top$ follows the matrix Riccati equation:
$$
\frac{d P}{dt} = P A + A P - 2 P A P,\quad P(0) = V V^\top,
$$
where $V\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$ has orthonormal columns, and $A$ is a symmetric strictly positive definite matrix. The solution to the above ODE is known:
$$
P(t) = e^{At} V (V^\top e^{2At} V)^{-1} V^\top e^{At}.
$$
**My question**: can one say the solution for $X(t)$ is
$$
X(t) = e^{At} V (V^\top e^{2At} V)^{-1/2},
$$
if $X(0)=V$? Any comment is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the original ODE for $X$?  To check if your solution is correct, plug it in and see if both sides are equal (perhaps after simplification).